# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while changing Image and Label

Tags: swift, image, storyboard, label

I am trying to change a picture and a label programmatically.

Here's the current code setup:

```
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setlabel()
    setImage()
}

func setImage(){
    self.image.image = UIImage(named: name)
}

func setlabel(){
    self.label.text = string
}
```

But unfortunately, I'm receiving nil for both UI elements, the label and the image. I've doublechecked the connection between my storyboard and the variables- they are set correctly, imho. They are available, since I am calling them outside the viewDidLoad function.

Anyone any suggestion?

Regards

Comment: Is this your initial ViewController?

Comment: Yes, this is my initial ViewController.

Comment: Instead of trying that in `viewDidLoad` try it in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: it is now recommended by Apple not to put weak in the IBOutlet variable definitions

Comment: I tried it in viewWillAppear, same result. And I also deleted the weak keyword- but this did not affect the behaviour.

Comment: @KarloKraljic can you share demo project?

Comment: can you share the exact line of code where its showing nil value

Comment: It is the line where I am trying to access the fields of the UI objects-

    self.image.image = ....
    self.label.text = ....

Comment: it would be great if you could share the demo project as i am able to execute the above code in my project and its not showing any error

Comment: Show screenshot of your links in the storyboard

Comment: Are you sure that `UIImage(named: name)` and `string` are not nil?

Comment: Logically, if one side of an equation is not nil (the outlet), then the other side is (the image and/or string). Put a breakpoint in your program and check if you have a UIImage and a string.

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, the outlets "image" and "label" are nil.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any issue with the code. It the outlets are connected to the storyboard's objects and they are in the project module then the outlets should not show nil value and crash. 

Can you check that the viewController in the storyboard is a part of your project module

Comment: Your code part is correct it just seems to be some error in connection making from storyboard to view controller. Please check the connection again. If nothing found, remove the connections and again connect them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had 2 views- let's call them A and B.

A contained a button- and the button had 2 functions: Change the view and set the labels/images. Those functions were defined in the Controller of view A.

Since I wanted to change the labels and images of view B, I got the exception.

I had to include another Controller and transfer the functions for setting the images and labels to Controller B. Voila, I could change the images and labels.

Summarized: I had the right connections and the right functions, but in the wrong place.

Thank you all!